# How to increase verbosity in python unittest?

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing, pydev, verbosity

I have a test case `class` like this one:

```
import unittest
import sys

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        pass
    def test_b(self):
        pass
    # etc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

This is a file in eclipse using PyDev. I run it as *unittest*. Somehow the verbosity option does not trigger. There are no errors. What do I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out, that the Answer is in the **eclipse configuration** and not in the source code.

Open **Preferences -> PyDev -> PyUnit** and adjust the **Parameters for test runner** field. change `--verbosity0` to `--verbosity2` or whatever number you like. <strike>Unfortunately I don't know, how high you can set this.</strike>

As @Jace pointed out in the comments the verbosity-levels range from `--verbosity0` to `--verbosity9`.

Comment: The same preferences menu says you can "hover for description" of each parameter:

    0: almost no output
    9: many details

Answer (score 0):

Set the `verbosity=0` (or 1 up to 2 ) in the `Parameters for test runner` field of `pyUnit` windows preference in Eclipse.

[image: Screenshot reference]