# unittest: increase module's verbosity when tested

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a module `mymodule` that I test with `unittest`. The module logs to stdout diagnostics messages when is in *verbose mode* (e.g. `mymodule.set_verbose(True)`) and remains silent otherwise. I would like that when I import the module in the main program it is in the *silent mode* and when the `unittest` runs, it is verbose.

I tried to hack it in the unittest main loop, but it doesn't work

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  mymodule.set_verbose( True )
  unittest.main() 
# apparently, modules are loaded on each test separately
```

[How to increase verbosity in python unittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429577/how-to-increase-verbosity-in-python-unittest) was not helpful.

Comment: related: [How to run initialization code before tests when using Python's unittest module as a testrunner?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8607767/95735)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `set_verbose` from the `setUp` method of the unittest.

Comment: Of course, so simple. Thanks. By the way can I make setUp on the higher level, so I don't need to run it in every test Class? I could make it by inheriting TestCase..., but maybe there is some default unittest-ish way

Comment: @JakubM. There is and it's called `setUpModule()` - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12904030/95735) answer.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: dzięki, apparently it's worth reading docpages from time to time

Answer (score 12):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Comment: Just so others know, the `verbosity` parameter wasn't added until Python 2.7.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you could directly use `unittest.TextTestRunner` to run your tests. This allows to set the verbosity level:

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestCaseClass)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

This will run all your tests from within `TestCaseClass`.

Comment: Verbosity passed to `TextTestRunner` partain to test runner itself and has nothing to do with `set_verbose()` function defined in the module being tested.